# Access VBA: Setting RecordSource of form as a RecordSet

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two form. One will display records form a RecordSet that the other form will point to.

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()

        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Forms("reportSelection").Controls("reportComboBox").value)
        RecordSource = rs

    End Sub
```

So, when the display form loads, it will grab the value from a combobox populated with recordset names in the other form, and open it as a recordset.

But I'm getting a type mismatch at RecordSource = rs, I dont understand why, how is RecordSource a different type than RecordSet?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: RecordSource wants an SQL query as a String.

Comment: @Cularis: you should copy your comment in an answer, so that it can be accepted....

Comment: For what it's worth, if you feel you MUST create the recordset yourself (instead of letting Access do it based on the Recordsource SQL string), you can assign the rs to the form's Recordset property. There may be some scope issues, though -- I wouldn't know, as I don't see any reason to use anything but the form's Recordsource...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to supply a SQL query as a String to the RecordSource Property.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.RecourdSource = "SELECT Hello FROM World" 
End Sub
```

Some [docs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/recordsource-property-HA001232789.aspx) you [might](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/change-the-record-source-or-connection-information-HP005187656.aspx) find [helpful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216003(v=office.12).aspx).

Comment: That works great! Mind helping me out with syntax?:
RecordSource = "select from [" & Forms("reportSelection").Controls("reportComboBox").value & "] order by Count where Count > 0" gives me error: "select statement includes a reserved word or argument contains name misspelled or missing, or punctuation is incorrect". Can you think of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't selecting a column. And count is a reserved word, but it in brackets [count] where [count] > 0.

Comment: I changed it to:  RecordSource = "select * from [" & Forms("reportSelection").Controls("reportComboBox").value & "] order by [Count] where [Count] > 0" and now I'm getting error: "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Count] where [Count] > 0'. Any idea on what I'm missing?

Comment: This should be a new question, but: where goes before the order (missed that before) and are you sure you have a column called count in the selected table`?

Comment: Yep just figured it out! Where goes before order. and it works! THanks for all the help!