# Previous record and Primary key being inappropriately overwritten in a MS Access form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a form in MS Access. I have written code where I can search my DB by the primary key and it adds all the fields to my form for editing, only the primary key doesn't change and I end up overwriting the previous record (on the form).

For the record my primary key is an auto-number field.

```vb
'Search function template
 Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

Dim recs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSearchID As String, sSQL As String

'SIN number to search (uses one in box)

sSearchID = Me.txtSearchSin
    
'Connect to the local database
Call DB_Connect

'Select query
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM sin_log WHERE sin_id = " & sSearchID & ";"
Debug.Print (sSQL)
    
'Run query and open recordset
recs.Open sSQL, conn, adOpenKeyset

'If records are found then populate form
If recs.RecordCount > 0 Then

    'In the case of duplicates this will be the value of the first record
    Me.txtSinId.Value = recs.Fields("sin_id").Value
    Me.date_recorded.Value = recs.Fields("date_recorded").Value
    Me.cmbSiteID.Value = recs.Fields("site_id").Value
    Me.cmbSite.Value = recs.Fields("site").Value
    Me.cmbZIP.Value = recs.Fields("ZIP").Value
    Me.cmbClient.Value = recs.Fields("client").Value
    Me.cmbDepot.Value = recs.Fields("depot").Value
    Me.cmbDriver.Value = recs.Fields("driver").Value
    Me.txtClassification.Value = recs.Fields("classification").Value
    Me.cmbIssue.Value = recs.Fields("issue").Value
    Me.txtDriverDescription.Value = recs.Fields("Issue description (as per driver)").Value
    Me.txtActionTaken.Value = recs.Fields("Action taken").Value
    Me.txtSiteAdvised.Value = recs.Fields("Site Aware").Value
    Me.txtActionBySite.Value = recs.Fields("Action taken by site").Value
    Me.cmbStatus.Value = recs.Fields("Open / Closed").Value
    Me.txtSinClosed.Value = recs.Fields("Sin Closed").Value
    
'else notify user
Else
    MsgBox "No record found for SIN #" & sSearchID
End If

'Close recordset
recs.Close

'Close the local database
Call DB_Close
```

Comment: Could you explain your issue a little more and how we could help?

Comment: Apologies, I am very new to this! 

I am trying to create a search function on my form for my database.

I have a separate txt box which you can enter the "SIN_Number" which is my primary key.

I can pull the data through to my form to edit via SQL that matches the primary key, but it wont bring through the exact record only the information and therefore will either overwrite information of another record or create a new one.

E.g. If I search for record 15 while just entered record 42 it will overwrite record 42 with record 15s data.

I hope this is more clear.

Comment: No problem, just maybe show what you want to happen and what is currently happening.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to post pictures yet. What is happening is that its pulling the data of record 15 (record I want to edit) but under record 42 (record that was last on my form). Rather than pulling through the actual record 15. I'm really sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I've answered below, showing two different ways that you can accomplish what you want. If you need anything else, please comment there. And, if useful, mark as answer and thumbs up.

Comment: Works like a treat, thank you so much

Comment: @JarrydMulligan, if it worked, it is advisable to mark the below answer as an Answer, so anyone looking for the same question knows that there is a working answer; SO functions as a Q & A site, like an Encyclopedia

Comment: @JarrydMulligan, the other advantage of marking as answered is that when people return the results of a search, they usually click on the questions that already have an answer, of course; this increases the chances that yours will be seen and increases the chances that yours will be voted on.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Jarryd!

As I see, you are not filtering your [Form's recordsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930614/access-vba-setting-recordsource-of-form-as-a-recordset) , you are really overwriting the previous value with the new one when you do this:

```
 Me.txtSinId.Value = recs.Fields("sin_id").Value
```

If you are trying to filter the Form's records by any value, you should do this:

```
Me.RecourdSource = "SELECT * FROM sin_log WHERE sin_id = " & sSearchID & ";"
```

You can do this at Design view too, of course with a parametrized query instead:

[image: Example of Design view Form recordsource]

The biggest value of Access's forms is that they are already bind to RecordSource fields, every time you pick fields from table or use the form wizard. You will end up with Form's fields and:

[image: Editing field's source]

Doing this way, you will not open and close any connection at cmdSearch_Click() handler.

You can, of course, [create unbound forms](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/unbound-forms.html), but it is a more advanced scenario, and I suggest that you stick with the Access's way of doing [RAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development) things.
Anyway, in case of unbound form you will need to, instead, open and close connection's in form's load. In search button you will only need to `Me.RecourdSource = "SELECT * FROM sin_log WHERE sin_id = " & sSearchID & ";"`